# Вывод объема оперативной памяти

Tags: c++, winapi

Здравствуйте! Есть задание вывести общий объём физической памяти и свободный объём физической памяти в Мб. Использую структуру MEMORYSTATUS из библиотеки Windows.h

```
    MEMORYSTATUS ms;
GlobalMemoryStatus(&ms);
label20->Text = Convert::ToString((int)ms.dwTotalPhys / 1024 / 1024) + "Mb";
label22->Text = Convert::ToString((int)ms.dwAvailPhys / 1024 / 1024) + "Mb";
```

Кол-во свободной памяти выводит правильно, с диспетчером задач сверил, а вот общий объём вывел неправильно, у меня 4 Гб.
Снизу скрин выполнения программы. Как решить эту проблему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В самом начале [страницы MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa366586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), посвященной `GlobalMemoryStatus`, написано:

**GlobalMemoryStatus** can return incorrect information. Use the **GlobalMemoryStatusEx** function instead.

В переводе:

**GlobalMemoryStatus** может возвращать неверную информацию. Используйте вместо нее функцию [**GlobalMemoryStatusEx**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa366589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Выдает отрицательное значение

Comment: Дайте код, pls.

Comment: MEMORYSTATUSEX ms;
 ms.dwLength = sizeof(ms);
 GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&ms);
 label20->Text = Convert::ToString((int)ms.ullTotalPhys / 1024 / 1024) + "Mb";
 label22->Text = Convert::ToString((int)ms.ullAvailPhys / 1024 / 1024) + "Mb";

Comment: И какой у вас размер `int`? вы просто режете 64-битную информацию до 31 бита и хотите чего-то... Это - `ms.ullTotalPhys` - значение `long long`...

Comment: Использовать long int?

Comment: Нет, использовать `long long`.

Comment: Хех, заработало)